# Custom UITableViewCell not showing on table view

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to create a custom `UITableViewCell`. Here is the code:

```
class ImportedContactsTVCell: UITableViewCell {

var nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
var emailLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))
var phoneLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 20))

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    nameLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    emailLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    phoneLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(emailLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(phoneLabel)

    var viewsDict = [

        "nameLabel" : nameLabel,
        "emailLabel" : emailLabel,
        "phoneLabel" : phoneLabel
    ]

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[nameLabel]-[emailLabel]-[phoneLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions( 0 ), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[nameLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions( 0 ), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[emailLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions( 0 ), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-[phoneLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions( 0 ), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
}
```

And I am using it as follows:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = ImportedContactsTVCell()
    cell.nameLabel.text = "A"
    cell.emailLabel.text = "B"
    cell.phoneLabel.text = "C"

    return cell
}
```

Their are no prototype cells created on storyboard. What am I missing please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I personally find it easier to make a XIB file with the interface of the cell in it and a `UITableViewCell` subclass to go along with it which provides access to the labels on your XIB. Then at your `cellForRowAtPath:` you would simply set the cell equal to your custom cell (simplifying here) and set your data.

Comment: What is happening when you run it? Just blank cells?

Comment: @Mikael yes. Just plain white blank cells.

Comment: Does the app run cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes. It steps through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` is not going to be called for a cell that you make entirely in code. You should override `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`, and put the code in there. You can still instantiate the cell with `ImportedContactsTVCell()` since you don't want any of the style choices. If you're using more than a few cells though, you should be using the normal dequeue mechanism to create your cells.

Answer (score -1):

You must have a prototype cells in storyboard. No way to create a table view cell without reuse

Ref to http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Comment: This is incorrect. You can create your cells in a xib, or entirely in code.

Comment: The first statement is not true. You don't *need* prototype cells on a storyboard, but creating the cell manually is not a good idea either.
It's better to register the class for the cell identifier  on `viewDidLoad`